# NullReference exception when using AddPrecalculatedGraph

Tags: c#, microsoft-glee, msagl

i need to to some work with Edge object before adding it to graph, so i create it like this

```
private void AddNewEdgeToGraph(string sourceNodeID, string targetNodeID)
    {
        Edge newEdge = new Edge(sourceNodeID, "", targetNodeID);
        newEdge.LabelText = newEdge.Attr.Weight.ToString();
        graph.AddPrecalculatedEdge(newEdge);
    }
```

And, as you have guessed, i get the NullReferenceException on the last line of code. I doubleChecked the parameters for correctness, and i am sure the graph contains nodes with such IDs. I have also tried to add Edges this way:

```
Edge newEdge = new Edge(graph.FindNode("path1"), graph.FindNode("path2"), 
     ConnectionToGraph.Connected);
newEdge.LabelText = newEdge.Attr.Weight.ToString();
graph.AddPrecalculatedEdge(newEdge);
```

And this one works correctly. I thought that the first variant uses the second underneath the hood, so what may be the problem?

Comment: Speculating, but I think the `ConnectionToGraph.Connected` has to do with initializing the `Edge` type for proper usage.

Comment: See marked duplicate for extensive advice regarding diagnosis and resolution of `NullReferenceException` problems. If you are unable to solve your problem with that information, post a new question in which you take the time to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, and a detailed, precise explanation of what debugging you've done so far, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.